# CORS Preflight Error: Working in Postman but Fails with Authenticated Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, cors, fetch-api, preflight

I'm trying to call an api to fetch user profile, but getting blocked by cors preflight error.

```
const username = 'username';
const password = 'password';
const credentials = `${username}:${password}`;
const base64Credentials = btoa(credentials);
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Basic ${base64Credentials}`,
    'Accept': '*/*'
}
const url = 'http://localhost:8080/account/' + username;
const method = "GET";

const callApi = () => {
    fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        headers: headers,
    }).then(res => {
        res.json().then(data => console.log(data));
    })
}
```

End point for getting user profile:

```
public ResponseEntity<ProfileDto> getUser(@PathVariable String username) {
            Optional<Account> accountOptional = accountRepository.findByUsername(username);
            if(accountOptional.isPresent()) {
                  Account account = accountOptional.get();
                  ProfileDto profileDto = new ProfileDto(
                          .....
                          .....
                          .....
                  );
                  return new ResponseEntity<>(profileDto, HttpStatus.FOUND);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
      }
```

Cors configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry
                    .addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:5500")
                    .allowedMethods("GET", "POST")
                    .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "Authorization", "Accept")
      }
}
```

Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
      @Bean
      public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            httpSecurity
                    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception
                            .authenticationEntryPoint(
                                    (req, res, ex) -> {
                                          res.sendError(
                                                  HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                                                  ex.getMessage()
                                          );
                                    }
                            )
                    )
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                            .requestMatchers( "/account").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
            return httpSecurity.build();
      }
}
```

I tried testing with postman.
All api's are working when spring security is set to permit all but not working when set to authenticated.

```
httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().permitAll())
```

authentication entry point hasn't detected the error.

Comment: I have tried everything I could, but, I was unable to find the solution.

Comment: If you have ”tried everything” why doesnt your code look like code in the  documentation i linked. Look at the first code example in the docs.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I tried that too, still getting error for authenticated api's then I tried [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc-cors.html#mvc-cors-global) config.

Comment: saying "i tried that too" doesn't help anyone. The code you have published in the question does not match the code in the documentation. Im not going to help you how much you even try to unless you actually read the docs and understand your problem because it is quite clear you havnt read the docs.

Comment: I've realized that the security filter is coming before CORS that's why only authenticated api' didn't work. Initially, I attempted to configure it like this: `configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:5500");`
However, in my browser, I used http://127.0.0.1:5500, and they didn't match. Got confused after this.

Comment: Have you tried to set `.allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "PUT")` instead of `.allowedMethods("GET", "POST")`  yet ? It is going to fix your problem. And also add it as a part of `securityFilterChain` somethig like this `httpSecurity.cors(corsConfigurer -> corsConfigurer.configurationSource("yourCorsBean"))` or `httpSecurity.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine when the request doesn't need any authentication.
But when the it need authentication security filter will validate it first. Since cors is not enabled in security filter, prefilght request fails.

Here is what the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html) says.

> CORS must be processed before Spring Security because the pre-flight request will not contain any cookies (i.e. the JSESSIONID). If the request does not contain any cookies and Spring Security is first, the request will determine the user is not authenticated (since there are no cookies in the request) and reject it.

To solve this, create a corsConfigurationSource bean and add it to to security filter.

Here is modified code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
  
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://127.0.0.1:5500");  // your domain
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST")); // yout methods
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-Type", "Authorization")); // your headers
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true); // for cookies
  
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

By deafult `httpSecurity.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())` searches for a bean named corsConfigurationSource. Refer [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html) for more.